# automatically create Python class factory from __init__.py

Tags: python

This code assigns the class name in a `dict` to the class. I've been manually adding to `feature_expander_factory` and find this inefficient, especially if the class name changes or a class is added.

Instead, I'd like to create `feature_expander_factory` from the `__init__.py` below. So it should take every class from the `__init__.py` file and then create a ` where the class name is assigned to the class.

```
from data_processing.feature_expanders import (
  CategoricalToOneHot,
  RFMSplitter,
  RFMSplitterAndOneHot,
  StrToListToColumns,
)

feature_expander_factory = dict(
  CategoricalToOneHot=CategoricalToOneHot,
  RFMSplitter=RFMSplitter,
  RFMSplitterAndOneHot=RFMSplitterAndOneHot,
  ListToColumns=StrToListToColumns,
)
```

`__init__.py`

```
from data_processing.feature_expanders.AbstractFeatureExpander import AbstractFeatureExpander
from data_processing.feature_expanders.CategoricalToOneHot import CategoricalToOneHot
from data_processing.feature_expanders.RFMSplitter import RFMSplitter
from data_processing.feature_expanders.RFMSplitterAndOneHot import RFMSplitterAndOneHot
from data_processing.feature_expanders.StrToListToColumns import StrToListToColumns
```

Comment: Why don't you create this dictionary?

Comment: @mkrieger1 what do you mean? You mean writing it myself like above or you referring to something else?

Comment: Sorry, I may not have grasped what you are asking. You said you wanted to create this dictionary, so I was trying to get a clarification what is preventing you from doing it.

Comment: well I'm trying to automatically generate the dict from the __init__.py rather than typing it manually. Sorry that wasn't super explicit.

Comment: Modules and packages already have a mapping of names in scope, it's their `__dict__` attribute. How is this any different from the existing module/package namespace?

Comment: @Gooby, what is the point of this? I recommend you add how you want to use the `feature_expanded_factory`, so the community may suggest more relevant solutions. P.S. I have a few answers in my head but not sure I entirely understand the context of the question.

Comment: is there a typo in that last sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Given a `feature_expanders.py` that has

```
class FeatureExpander:
    pass

class A(FeatureExpander):
    pass

class B(FeatureExpander):
    pass

class C(FeatureExpander):
    pass
```

you can do something like

```
import feature_expanders

def is_feature_expander_class(val):
    try:
        return issubclass(val, feature_expanders.FeatureExpander) and val != feature_expanders.FeatureExpander
    except TypeError:  # issubclass requires a class
        return False

feature_expander_factory = {fx.__name__: fx for fx in vars(feature_expanders).values() if is_feature_expander_class(fx)}
print(feature_expander_factory)
```

to get

```
{'A': <class 'feature_expanders.A'>, 'B': <class 'feature_expanders.B'>, 'C': <class 'feature_expanders.C'>}
```

and from there you could do `feature_expander_factory['A']()`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve kind of this is to decorate the feature expander classes with simple decorator that updates the feature_expander_factory dictionary.

```py
# feature_expanders.py

feature_expander_factory = {}

def expander(cls):
    feature_expander_factory[cls.__name__] = cls
    return cls


@expander
class AbstractFeatureExpander:
    ...

@expander
class CategoricalToOneHot:
    ...
```

```py
# other-python-file.py

from feature_expanders import feature_expander_factory

print(feature_expander_factory)
```

Outputs:

```py
{
    'AbstractFeatureExpander': <class 'feature_expanders.AbstractFeatureExpander'>,
    'CategoricalToOneHot': <class 'feature_expanders.CategoricalToOneHot'>
}
```

Please elaborate your use case so we could suggest some more suitable for you.